# C++ Variable expressions for defining array size?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2012

I'm a newb at C++ and I practice coding on my school computer, so I have to use an online compiler (www.CompileOnline.com).  I have a variable that is defined by a function and is then used to initialize an array like so:

int var = function(a);

int num[var];

This code works just fine on the website, but on Visual Studio Express 2012 it gives me an error:

C2057: expected constant expression

Is this a problem with Visual Studio? I've read that it's a C++ rule, but then why does it work on the website? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You're making a variable-length array, which is a feature that vs2012 apparently doesn't support.  [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feature that the code snippet requires is called [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (VLAs). Support for this feature in the C or C++ language depends on the compiler and the version of the standard.

- C99 supports VLAs as standard.
- Versions earlier than C99 (includes C90) do not support VLAs as standard, but some compilers may implement it as a language extension.
- C11 makes VLAs an *optional* feature.
- C++14 supports a restricted variant of VLAs called *dynamic arrays*.
- Versions earlier than C++14 (includes C++11, C++03, and C++98) do not support VLAs as standard, but some compilers may implement it as an extension.

In particular, [GCC implements VLAs as a language extension for C90 and C++](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html), and apparently www.compileonline.com uses GCC as the compiler (version 4.7.2 as of this writing). No version of the Visual C++ compiler implement VLAs.

[Herb Sutter talks about C++14's dynamic array feature](http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/04/trip-report-iso-c-spring-2013-meeting):

> In the language, draft C++14 now allows stack-based arrays to have a size determined at run time:
>
> ```
> void f(std::size_t n)
> {
>    int a[n];
>
>    ...
>
> }
> ```
>
> Note that this is not the same as C99 variable length arrays (VLAs),
>   and that the C11 standard has made VLAs conditionally-supported so
>   that they are no longer part of portable C required in a conforming C
>   compiler. In particular, C++ explicitly not does support the following
>   features from C99 VLAs which C++ feels are not desirable:
>
> - multidimensional arrays, where other than the top level has a runtime
>     bound (in analogy, the array form of new expressions doesn’t support
>     that either)
> - modifications to the function declarator syntax
> - `sizeof(a)` being a runtime-evaluated expression returning the size of `a`
> - `typedef int a[n];` evaluating `n` and passing that through the typedef

If you want C++ code that works in pretty much any version of C++, consider using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int var = function(a); // Assume function() has been defined.
    std::vector<int> num(var); // Creates a vector with var number of elements.
    // ...
    int num1 = num[1]; // You can access elements in vectors just like arrays.
    num[1] += 10;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: For everyone reading this now: The extension has NOT made it into C++14. Dynamic Arrays are still only allowed on the heap, such as by `auto foo = new int[n];`

Answer (score 1):

Variable length arrays are not allowed in C++. The size of the array must be determinable at compile time.

CompileOnline.com says it uses GNU GCC version 4.7.2. GCC has an extension that supports [variable length arrays](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) in C++:

> Variable-length automatic arrays are allowed in ISO C99, and as an extension GCC accepts them in C90 mode and in C++.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the online compiler is [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/) which implement variable length arrays as an extension in C++. The "problem" in this case is actually gcc, not VC++: gcc implement an extension which enables by default, tricking users into creating non-portable code.

If you need a variable sized array in C++, you'd include `<vector>` and use the class template declared in this header, e.g.:

```
int var = function(a);
std::vector<int> num(var);
```